# Is it bad design to have a business logic object prompt the user for input?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I have a flow chart that I'm implementing and it has 4 or 5 paths through it depending on user input and the results of some processing. Naturally, I don't want all this logic this in my Windows form, I just want to call a method on the class in the form. Is it bad design to have my business logic class reference System.Windows.Forms and show dialogs and MessageBoxes to get the input it needs to process and return a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is bad design. Your class should offer a mean to communicate with the form and get data back. Just create events and let the `Form` subscribe to them, getting the information to create the dialogs from a custom `EventArgs` class. After it gets the input, just push the same class back with the additional information via a second event.

This should resemble the MVP pattern.

Comment: The MVP pattern I belive, no?

Comment: This was my first inclination of what to do. I guess I was just looking for someone to validate it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that should be true, nick. However, I think the example was better suited, I should've mentioned it though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a bad idea. You are effectively coupling your business logic very tightly with the presentation. You (probably won't) be able to re-use business logic easily under other circumstances, and you won't be able to replace the UI without touching the business logic.

You need to have the UI and business logic layers communicate, and let the UI layer handle, well, the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's bad design. When you separate components of your application, a rule of thumb is to keep them separate enough so that you can run them on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because it means your busienss object is simply not a business obejct.

Use a MVVM pattern and put the logic into the viewmodel.

Comment: I'd suspect that MVC would be more appropriate for WinForms, though I guess the exact pattern used is less relevant than using a well-vetted pattern.

Comment: I think the event-based MVP pattern is also an option. The view fires events and the presenter handles them in its magical, mystical way.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad design, because you may need to run your business logic in a situation with a different UI or no UI at all (such as in a server, or a batch process).  That's what separation of business logic and UI is all about.  If possible, it's better to get all the necessary user input up-front in the UI class before handing things off to the business logic.  However, if it's necessary to have the business logic prompt for more information, then it's better for the business logic API to take a callback method delegate, which it can call to request the further input.  Then the UI layer can decide how best to request from the user.